# java regex match any string, specific string , any string, specific string and any string

Tags: java, regex

I need to find picture location in HTML text based on regex.

e.g.

The HTML string is:

```
    <div style='background-image: url(http://www.mydomain.com/images/test.jpg); 
background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; height: 400px;'>
```

And I need to define a regex that will find the end location of string that starts with http://www.mydomain.com and finishes with ).

1. What should be the regex?
2. How can I find the end location in java?

Comment: Might the `http://www.mydomain.com` appear elsewhere in the HTML you are parsing? Or can your regex just start with the hard-coded URL and capture the rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this to find the url:

```
String input = "<div style='background-image: url(http://www.mydomain.com/images/test.jpg); \n" +
                "background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; height: 400px;'>";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("image:\\surl\\(([^)]+)\\)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()){
    String url = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(url);
}
```

or

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("image:\\surl\\(http://www\\.mydomain\\.com([^)]+)\\)");
```

if you want to have only what follows the domain part

Comment: Then use `lastIndex` on `/` to parse it. Then assumes only one `image` tag in the HTML being parsed.

Comment: This is not working for me. Because if I have the following: <div style='background-image: url((http://www.mydomain.com/images/test.jpg); color: rgb(112, 47, 43)' > The end location is 3) (from the rgb) and not the end of image ulr

Comment: edited regexp to catch  string only before first closing ")" after domain name :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be something like this:

```
www\\.mydomain\\.com.*/([\\w-\\.]*)
```

When run on `<div style='background-image: url(http://www.mydomain.com/images/test.jpg); 
background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; height: 400px;'>`

Group # 1 = `test.jpg`

Comment: I tried it as well. <div style='background-image: url(http://www.mydomain.com/images/products/HappyBirthday1.jpg);> group1 returned to me div